# Worst-case running time using Big-Θ notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o, code-analysis, analysis

I understand that the innermost for loop is Θ(logn)
 and the two outermost for loops is Θ(n^2) because it's an arithmetic sum. The if-statement is my main problem. Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
int tally=0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i ++)
{
   for (int j = i; j < n; j ++)
   {
        if (j % i == 0)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k < n; k *= 2)
            { 
                tally++;
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
Now I noticed loop order: `i` before `j`.

In this case for given `i` value `j` varies from `i` to `n` and there are `(n/i)` successful if-conditions.

So program will call then most inner loop

```
n/1 +n/2+n/3+..+n/n
```

times. This is sum of [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), it converges to `n*ln(n)`

So inner loop will be executed `n*log^2(n)` times.

As you wrote, two outermost loops provide `O(n^2)` complexity, so overall complexity is `O(n^2 + n*log^2(n))`, the first term overrides the second one,  loop, and finally overall complexity is quadratic.

```
int tally=0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i ++)
{  
   // N TIMES
   for (int j = i; j < n; j ++)
   {  
     //N*N/2 TIMES
        if (j % i == 0)
        {
         //NlogN TIMES
            for (int k = 1; k < n; k *= 2)
            { 
             //N*logN*logN
                tally++;
            }
        }
   }
}
```

---

Old answer (wrong)

This complexity is linked with sum of [sigma0(n) function](https://oeis.org/A000005) (number of divisors) and represented as [sequence A006218](https://oeis.org/A006218) ([Dirichlet Divisor problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletDivisorProblem.html))

We can see that  approximation for sum of divisors for values up to n is

```
  n * ( log(n) + 2*gamma - 1 ) + O(sqrt(n))
```

so average number of successful if-conditions for loop counter `j` is `~log(j)`

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that I'm trying to find the worst case runtime. Would ~log(j) happen to also be the worst case while being the average case?

Comment: @okamiaaron I've completely rewritten solution

Comment: @MBo - I really like the in-depth answer (+1), but in this particular case I would call it `N^2 / 2` as the heaviest operation seems to be the modulo `%`.

Comment: @MBo This definitely cleared things up. But wouldn't n*log^2(n) be the runtime of the second for loop and everything inside it, meaning the overall running time would be (n^2)*log^2(n)?

Comment: Code after `if` has runtime `n*log^2(n)`. But after `~n^2` if-operators only `~n*log(n)` further calls occur. I added estimated call count scheme.

Comment: @MBo I see, thank you for the response. Since the only line of code being repeated is `tally++`, wouldn't we just say that the total runtime is `n*log^2(n)`? Wouldn't the runtime only be `n^2 + n*log^2(n)` if there was code right before or after the if statement?

Comment: There is pitfall: line ` if (j % i == 0)` is repeated more times. In estimation of run times one should account for both significant code lines (like `tally++`) and comparison operations (like if's) and swaps etc. If you have clear problem statement - count only significant lines - then answer is `n*log^2(n)` but in general case - `n^2`

Comment: If I were instructor, I would be glad to see any solution but together with reasoning and considering both approaches (yes, I realize that some ones expect only answer from their book)